# What is this unknown part?

Tags: identification

I'm tracing a circuit. What is this part?

[image: one side of component]

This is back of it.

[image: other side of component]

Answer (score 24):

It's a 1A  125°C (nominal) thermal fuse, rated to fuse at 121°C +/-2°C

Operating temperature is up to 100°C.

Made by [Xiamen SET Electronics Co.](http://www.setfuse.com/product/over-temperature-protection/thermal-cutofftco/radial-shape/f-series.html), Ltd in Xiamen China.

[image]

It is not resettable. Needs to be replaced.

Comment: Why can't I measure conduction in the two legs?

Comment: Maybe it's already burned out. Can't really tell from that photo- it should measure very low resistance. Or maybe you're not making good contact because the board is coated or whatever.

Comment: That would explain what looks like a bubble in there.

Comment: Before replacing it, consider looking for the reason why a device that is supposed never to go over 120°C, but needs costly measures to be really, really kept from going over 120°C, went over 120°C

Comment: I think @rackandboneman is suggesting that it would be a very bad idea to replace it with anything other than the original part number. It's also possible that something failed and took it out through a short rather than external high temperatures- it's only rated 1A so it will probably open up with excessive current fairly readily.

Comment: Follow rackandboneman's advice "Before replacing it, consider looking for the reason why a device that is supposed never to go over 120°C, but needs costly measures to be really, really kept from going over 120°C, went over 120°C" Judging by that solder job it appears to have been replaced before.

Answer (score 8):

It is called Thermal cut-off (TCO) /  Thermal fuse.

in the "SET F3" 3 indicates that it is rated to cut off at 121+/-2 ℃, 125 ℃(nominal temperature) rated for 100 ℃. where as F indicates rated for 1A load current.

Comment: If more than 1A passes through it. It can open too or only from temperature?

Comment: In the original post and picture, the legs are no longer conducting and I checked inside. It has opened already. So this can occur without any obvious ambient rise in temperature. Isn't it.

Comment: Its already burned out. these are single time operation devices. yeh may be.

Answer (score 5):

F1 indicates a fuse on the silk screen.
eg https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/littelfuse-inc/80812000440/WK6289-ND/2206338

Comment: Seems to be a thermofuse to me. No current noted, but 125°C.